# YARA Rules - Can you accumulate a value over a range of bytes and then comapre it?

Tags: yara

I'm trying to write a YARA rule which will iterate some range of bytes, will xor them with something and add to some accumulator in order to compare the final result with a predefined value

Is this possible? As far as I know you cannot declare variables in the condition section.

I have this `pe.sections[s].raw_data_offset` as the beginning of the stream I need to run on and `pe.sections[s].raw_data_offset+pe.sections[s].raw_data_size` as the end of it.